# I am not able to use the imports on torchrl or its modules. I am installing it from the official github repo https://github.com/pytorch/rl

Tags: python, conda, apple-m1

ImportError: cannot import name 'unravel_keys' from 'tensordict.utils'

This is the error being shown whenever I am trying to import any module. How do I solve this?
I am using a MacBook M1 with x86_64 architecture

I tried cloning the repo to my machine but it has some errors in the tensordict library.

Answer (score 4):

TorchRL is developed alongside TensorDict which you can find [here](https://github.com/pytorch-labs/tensordict)

If you're using the latest version of torchrl (from github) you will need to also install the latest version of tensordict and -- perhaps -- the latest pytorch

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pytorch-labs/tensordict
```

TorchRL also comes with nightly releases:

```
pip install tensordict-nightly torchrl-nightly
```